# Prompt user to enable SMS on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I am using `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send messages. I use `canSendText` before sending the SMS. However if `canSendText` returns false i would like to take the user to setting->messages in iPad so that he can turn on messages. Is there a URL Scheme or something other way I can do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was possible is iOS 5.0-5.0.1 using the `prefs:root=` url scheme. However, Apple promptly removed this ability in 5.1. Sorry your out of luck. The best we can do is keep filing bug reports on [Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/10198949) asking for this feature back.

**EDIT:** From what I've found, there is a way to still do this in 5.1+ for Twitter settings and this may work for messages as well, as long as the message controller conforms to UIAlertView delegate like the twitter controller does (personally not sure about this one), but it absolutely won't work for anything else. Maybe you're in luck after all!

http://goto11.net/programmatically-open-twitter-settings-on-ios-5-1/

Comment: I did as given in the example, it worked for twitter but for Messages
MFMessageComposeViewController *msg = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init]; 

if ([msg respondsToSelector:@selector(alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:)]) ... this if Condition never returns true

Comment: @ila I'm sorry to hear that, I thought there might be a slight possibility that that would work but if it didn't, then this is impossible to do.